# How to see the size of a OneNote notebook?

Tags: sync, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I have quite a few OneNote notebooks on my computer that are stored in the cloud, but also have backups locally on my hard drive. I estimate their sizes to be about 500 - 800 Mb. The thing I am looking for is a way to find their exact sizes. I have looked through OneNote and have not found a listing of the size.

I am sure that there is a probably an easy and obvious solution to this problem that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was wondering the same thing and found this question. I ended up finding out how to do it so I figured I'd post it here. These instructions are for when the notebook is stored in OneDrive.

Log into the OneNote app for Windows 10 and right click on your notebook's name. In the dropdown menu that shows up, there should be an option to copy the link to the notebook.

Paste this into a browser to open it up, but pay attention to the end of the link. For mine, the end looked like this.

https://d.docs.live.net/**********/Documents/NotebookNameHere/

That miniature link at the end of the full link gave a hint to where the Notebook was being stored, and clued me in to where to look in the next steps.

When you paste the full link from OneNote into the browser, the web version of OneNote will open.

Just under the purple header bar at the top left corner there will be some breadcrumbs. In my case, it displayed as Onedrive -> Documents.

Click the link all the way to the right, which in my case was Documents but may change based on where your notebook is stored. This will open OneDrive in that directory.

Once OneDrive was open in the directory, I was able to find a file icon for the OneNote notebook. If you right click on that, there will be a dropdown menu and the very bottom option should be Details. Select that, and you will be able to see the size of the notebook.

There might be a way to do this that is less of a pain, but I looked around for a while and didn't find an obvious one. Interesting note, if you try and get to the directory mentioned above from the desktop app, all you can see is a web shortcut to open the notebook. The shortcut is only a KB or so, so obviously not the actual size of the notebook.

Answer (score 5):

Came here looking for the answer and then found it.

1. Go to OneDrive.live.com (home page)
2. Select "My files" on left hand side
3. Change to detail view (on top right toolbar select the window icon drop down and change to "List")
   This for me was between the "Sort" option and the "i" button

Comment: This works as well! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at where the OneNote file is saved using the Save & Backup setting in **File**>**Options**>**Save & Backup**. Then I would open up a Command Prompt shell in that folder and run the `dir` command. This will tell you how large the file is in bytes.

Comment: This does not work, but I realize that it is my fault why you were lead in the wrong direction as I forgot to mention that my OneNote notebooks are stored in OneDrive (will update the question). When using this command when your notebooks are stored in OneDrive the only notebook that appears is titled _Quick Notes_. I am pretty sure that this would work on a notebook that is locally stored, though +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue and needed to know the size of OneNote notebook on OneDrive. Login to OneNote in web browser, select Manage and Delete on right side of grey bar. Navigate to the Notebook file, select file and right click, select details at bottom of context menu to see file size.

Comment: I would rather not have to delete my notebook to find this out, but thanks anyways!